# What does X.T in Python do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

I am very new to Python.  I am using the transpose operator in the numpy package:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> np.T(X)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    np.T(X)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'T'
```

Why is it that this is an error, yet `X.T` works?  Furthermore, `X.np.T` fails. On the other hand, `np.fft.fft(X)` succeeds, but `X.fft.fft` fails.

Thanks all!

Comment: I don't get the question. X and np are not the same thing, np is a module (it's an alias for numpy) and X is a numpy array. Obviously they are going to behave differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) function returns an [`ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arrays-ndarray) object, so when you call

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

the variable `X` is assigned an `ndarray`.  That object has a [`T`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T) method, which transposes the array.

Calling `T` like the following:

```
np.T(X)
```

doesn't work because the numpy library doesn't have a free-floating function named `T` that takes an array as an argument, just the method in the `ndarray` class.

Answer (score 2):

`X.T` means transpose of X.
For example lets say this is our X:

[image: X]

X.T is going to be:

[image: X.T]